# Can't install mysqlclient in CentOS 7

Tags: python, linux, centos, mysql-connector

First of all... not, it's not a repeated thread. Believe me, I read all similar threads and tested all answers before post this.

I just have a new CentOS 7 server installation, with basic configuration (the same I used several times before, but magically, this time does not work)

```
yum -y update
yum -y groupinstall development
yum -y install gcc
yum -y install zlib-devel
yum -y install openssl-devel
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install mariadb-devel
```

Python3.6

```
yum -y install python36
yum -y install python36-devel
```

However, once I create my virtual environment with: `python3 -m venv test` and try to install `mysqlclient` using `pip`... Simply doesn't work. The error I have is:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/www/test/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pn9v4w46/mysqlclient_d62f41676e4049d6a292a9525c56d5c9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pn9v4w46/mysqlclient_d62f41676e4049d6a292a9525c56d5c9/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7ethj5wf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/test/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pn9v4w46/mysqlclient_d62f41676e4049d6a292a9525c56d5c9/
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,2,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.2 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/var/www/test/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -m64
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c: En la función ‘_mysql_row_to_dict_cached’:
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1340:5: error: sólo se permiten las declaraciones iniciales del bucle ‘for’ en modo C99
         for (unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++) {
         ^
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:1340:5: nota: use la opción -std=c99 o -std=gnu99 para compilar su código
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /var/www/test/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pn9v4w46/mysqlclient_d62f41676e4049d6a292a9525c56d5c9/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-pn9v4w46/mysqlclient_d62f41676e4049d6a292a9525c56d5c9/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-7ethj5wf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/test/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

So... just for save us time, I already tried with all this libraries installed (just for test):
`mysql-devel`, `mysql-connector-python`, `zlib.i686`, `glibc.i686`, `MySQL-python`, even installing `mysql-server`. I mean... Because I can't find a logic answer to this situation I just test to install any library I suspect could help, but nothig works. Always the same error.

As I said, I read every single post with errors similar to this, tutorials to configure MySQL on CentOS 7 with django, etc, etc, and all libraries people say in this posts, I tried, but error persist.

I'm into this situation because my hard disk died and I need to configure all my development server from scratch, and I run into this issue for almost a week. So... basically I'm a bit desperate :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with version `2.0.2` and it is already [reported](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/460)

You could downgrade package to version `2.0.1` or set `CFLAG` to compile with C99 standard

```
export CFLAGS="-std=c99"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [github issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/460), the latest release has some issues with centos7. Recommend solution is to use the previous version (2.0.1)

```
pip3 install mysqlclient==2.0.1
```

Comment: OMG I never found that! I look into almost entire www less library repository LOL. Thanks a lot dude

Comment: glad it helped :)